# Play URL from Real time Database to Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am really new to android dev in general and especially to Exoplayer. i have setup all requirement for Real time data base to retrieve the url. my last attempt to make Exoplayer work is that i have created a new class to deal with real time database and store it in a TextView just to troubleshoot the link between firebase and android studio. It display the URL, but when i try to use it with Exoplayer it does not. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Below are my codes

```
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

    public class lounge extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView mFireText;
        Button mButton;
        String link;
        DatabaseReference mrootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference mlinkRef = mrootRef.child("Test_URL");
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_lounge);

            mFireText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        }

    public void storeLink(){
        Intent lIntent = new Intent(this, lounge.class);
        lIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_LINK",link);
    }
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mlinkRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String link  = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    mFireText.setText(link);
                    link = mFireText.getText().toString();



                }

//and Exoplayer code:

    public class MediaPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        PlayerView playerView;
        SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;





        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setFullScreen ();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_player);
            hideActionbar();
            Intent intent =getIntent();
            String link =intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_LINK");

            try {

                playerView = findViewById(R.id.exo_player);
                exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
                playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

                DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,Util.getUserAgent(this, "appname"));
                HlsMediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(link));
                exoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: How you are calling storeLink() method.

Comment: i think its not being called.  As i mentioned i am really new to developing, i just follow courses in order to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You are using exoplayer in MediaPlayerActivity so you have to start that activity from your current activity and pass link with intent. like

```
 String link;
 public void storeLink(){
    Intent lIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerActivity.class);
    lIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_LINK",link);
}
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mlinkRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                link  = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mFireText.setText(link);
                link = mFireText.getText().toString();
                storeLink();
            }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Hi Amit. Still the same issue. MfireText displays the link which means firebase access is granted. Yet, the the storeLink method is not actually storing the value into link. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi mit Tiwary, i have tried your suggestion but still not displaying anything. so i removed all firebase methods and used only store link method but again same issue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OqA5.png i have took a screenshot for reference.